Ctrl-k Ctrl-y stopped working
Just upgraded to 29.3 (not sure what I was on before), and I simultaneously upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1.
Now Ctrl-y doesn't "paste" what Ctrl-k "cut". But Ctrl-k is in the system buffer, i.e. I can paste it into a web browser, for example. This is the case in all modes that I have tried (org-mode, text mode, python mode).
Ctrl-y does paste whatever I last cut with an explicit Ctrl-Space Alt-w, ignoring a more recent Ctrl-k

Oops. It was the following line in my .emacs
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-get-selection-value)

I changed that from 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value after my upgrade, because x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value no longer exists. But it looks like that line is no longer needed at all. So all good.
